# How not to switch past the edge of panes in tmux

Tags: tmux

By default, tmux passes over edge of a pane. For example, suppose there are two panes, `pane 1` and `pane 2`. Suppose you're at `pane 1` and you do <kbd>Ctrl+b</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd>, you're at the `pane 2`. If you again do <kbd>Ctrl+b</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd>, you'll be again at `pane 1`. How can I disable that feature so, when I'm navigating from the last pane, I don't go anywhere?

Comment: There's a more concise solution to this posted here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215688/tmux-select-pane-ldur-command-disable-auto-cycling-behavior

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack but might be good enough for you. From version 2.3 you can find the x and y co-ordinate of each pane's borders. For example, `display -p #{pane_right}` for a pane at the right-hand edge of an 80 column terminal would be 79.  If you give the command to move right to the next pane, and the new pane's `pane_right` is, for example, 39, then you have moved left, so you will want to move back to the previous pane with `select-pane -l`.

You can run most tmux commands from a shell script, so create the following file `mytmux` in your PATH and make it executable (`chmod +x mytmux`):

```
#!/bin/bash
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/451473/119298
restrict(){
        case $1 in
        U)  d=-U p=pane_top    cmp=-gt ;;
        D)  d=-D p=pane_bottom cmp=-lt ;;
        L)  d=-L p=pane_left   cmp=-gt ;;
        R)  d=-R p=pane_right  cmp=-lt ;;
        *)  exit 1 ;;
        esac
        old=$(tmux display -p "#{$p}")
        tmux select-pane "$d"
        new=$(tmux display -p "#{$p}")
        [ "$new" "$cmp" "$old" ] && tmux select-pane -l
        exit 0
}
case $1 in
-restrict)shift
        restrict "${1?direction}" ;;
esac
```

then setup the following bindings in your `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
bind-key -r -T prefix Up    run-shell 'mytmux -restrict U'
bind-key -r -T prefix Down  run-shell 'mytmux -restrict D'
bind-key -r -T prefix Left  run-shell 'mytmux -restrict L'
bind-key -r -T prefix Right run-shell 'mytmux -restrict R'
```

You will need to extend this if you want to handle multiple sessions, for example.

Answer (score 3):

The <kbd>Prefix</kbd><kbd>Arrow</kbd> keys are by default bound like

```
bind-key -r -T prefix       Up                select-pane -U
bind-key -r -T prefix       Down              select-pane -D
bind-key -r -T prefix       Left              select-pane -L
bind-key -r -T prefix       Right             select-pane -R
```

The `select-pane` function does not have an option that tells it "don't cycle when you've reached the last pane in that direction".

Looking at the source code that is executed for `select-pane`, it looks like the cycling left/right and top/bottom is hard-coded in, which means that it's unlikely to be easy to stop it from behaving in this way.